# How can I scale up an indexed PNG and save it out in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, gdi+, png

I've gotten GDI+ to read a PNG, scale it up (nearest neighbor), and save it out, but unfortunately if I load an indexed PNG it still saves it out as a 32 bit PNG, which is a big waste.

I've seen some great 3rd party tools that let you load/save PNGs, but unfortunately I do not believe my host will allow it since it uses medium trust and these tools load COM DLLs.

I've been going down the path of using WPF libraries like PngBitmapEncoder (I am running .net 4), but I have not had any luck retaining the indexed setting here either when making a scaled copy of the PNG, let alone have I been able to figure out how to use nearest-neighbor scaling (which I did get working in GDI+).

Am I screwed? Time to start reading the bytes one by one? lol. I hope not because I certainly don't have that kind of background. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume use are using the Image::Save method to save the PNG. 
How exactly do you call Save - like this:

```
   CLSID pngClsid;
   GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &pngClsid);
   image.Save(L"Mosaic2.png", &pngClsid, NULL);
```

The third parameter (in the example above NULL) specifies parameters which are specific to the encoder - in this case the PNG encoder.

Have you checked to see what parameters are supported by the PNG encoder? Maybe you can specify the colorDepth.

Getting the parameters for an encoder:

- c++: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533840(v=vs.85).aspx
- c#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882589.aspx